# iOS user permission alert

Tags: ios, permissions, uilocalnotification

I have a little issue. I ask user permission for local notification through method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];`
. And system alert for permission is displayed. But in this alert option "Don't Allow" is bold. I want vice versa that 'OK' should be bold. I have googled and find that other application has 'OK' button bold. How could I achieve this? I could not find any settings for this. Thanks for helping

[image: example]

Comment: There's no way to customize those alerts. Are they from the same version of iOS?

Comment: Yeah I have tried both application on my iPhone